# Modify preg_replace to add span to both first letter and first word

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace, preg-match

I am using the following preg_replace code to add a -Tag around the first letter of a paragraph (in Wordpress):

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    the_content();
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    $content = preg_replace('@<p>\s*((?:<[^<>]+>\s*)*)([^<>\s])@', '<p>$1<span class="pst-Dropcap">$2</span>', $content, 1);

    echo $content;
?>
```

This results in something similar to this:

```
<p><span class="pst-Dropcap">H</span>ello world.</p>
```

I would like to extend this code so it will span the rest of the word with a different tag:

```
<p><span class="pst-Dropcap">H</span><span class="pst-First_Word">ello</span> world.</p>
```

How can this be achieved?

I am aware of the CSS pseudo-selector ::first-letter, I have different reasons for not using it in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
$content = preg_replace('@<p>\s*((?:<[^<>]+>\s*)*)([^<>\s])([^<>\s]*)@', '<p>$1<span class="pst-Dropcap">$2</span><span class="pst-First_Word">$3</span>', $content, 1);
```

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you very much! What does the additional
`([^<>\s])`
do?

Comment: Please note the * added to the second ([^<>\s]) pattern. That * means you can have that pattern 0 times OR many times. See this for more info : http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php